# RTE is not present for content elements in typo3 7.6

Tags: typo3-7.6.x

I am using TYPO3 7.6.9 with fluid template. I am trying to add a text as content element for text & Media content element. I want the text to be written in RTE field. But unfortunately, the RTE field is not showing for any of the content element. rtehtmlarea extension in activated in the extension manager. How can I have the rte field for the content elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have rte enabled in your user settings (tab: Edit & Advanced functions)?

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem arise due to some permission issue.Create a new admin backend user and try to login with new user.

Comment: Thanks Aswathy. For a particular user, by enabling RTE in user settings, we can activate RTE.